# Call a user control on a aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `UserControl`.

Markup:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="top.ascx.cs" Inherits="top" %>
<div id="viewSwitcher">
   <H1>HELLO WORLD</H1>
</div>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class top : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Now I want to call the user control on a `aspx` page? So I can test the user control and start writing a new one. How can I call a user control on a `aspx` page?

Comment: Did you embed the markup on the page, and register the control either on the page or in the web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register the control in your `web.config`.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
         <pages>
             <controls>
                 <add tagPrefix="my" tagName="top" src="~/Controls/top.ascx" />
             </controls>
         </pages>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Then you can use it in your markup on the page..

```
<my:top runat="server" />
```

This presumes that `top.ascx` is in a folder `~/Controls/` so you may need to adjust the path. By the way, it's a good idea to put each control in a separate folder `~/Controls/top/top.ascx` so that you can nest them if necessary.

Comment: Will this call all the ascx.cs on page load of that then @mason

Comment: @DomAdams Yes, you can see for yourself if you debug the app and set a breakpoint in your control's `Page_Load` function.